# How to simplify massive numbers of log files

Tags: ros, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you simplify ROS's logging system so it doesn't generate a massive number of log files?

I'm trying to diagnose a problem with a specific node crashing upon launch. So, the first thing I want to check is its logging output. Sounds simple, right? Unfortunately, it's quite a headache. I went to the default log directory in `~/.ros/log` and I see:

[image: image description]

What in the world is this? I have, maybe, 6 nodes running. Why are so many log files necessary? Where do I begin to find the one containing output from my node?

If this is the default, how do I override this so either:

1. everything goes to a single easily searchable log file?
2. name the log files by the name of the node that writes to them, instead of some meaningless UUID?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278565/how-to-simplify-massive-numbers-of-log-files/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2018-01-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-01-02**:
Cut-and-paste text instead of screenshots of text is a lot easier to read and analyze.

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2018-01-02**:
You want me to cut and paste the `ls` output showing the thousands of random log file names? How would that help you? Normally I'd agree that copy and paste is better, but not in this instance.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-01-02**:
Just capture about a screens worth of output, it could be exactly what is in the existing image except text, or less since it will be a bit bigger due to font size.  A `...` at the end could be added to say there is more output that has been excluded.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-05**:
Just an observation: from the screenshot it appears that someone/something is invoking `rosservice` (the command line utility) about every 7 or 8 seconds. As @mig already explained, each invocation will result in a log file. That would seem to be the primary cause of the many log files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was using `robot_upstart` to launch my `all.launch`, and apparently this package is still very buggy and unstable in 16.04, and no longer outputs any logging information to its documented upstart log file. I replaced this with `supervisor`, and my `all.launch` now works perfectly.

---

Originally posted by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) with karma: 940 on 2018-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2020-03-31**:
For the honor of `robot_upstart`, I use it at the production system dev for years and have never seen the issue like you described in the OP. I understand your frustration, and I have no way to disagree with your observation, but if you claim an OSS package to be "buggy" and "unstable", I'd much appreciate providing more concrete analysis.